# Line numbers from HUnit-Plus / Distribution.TestSuite / stack test failures?

Tags: haskell, testing

I'm using `HUnit-Plus` via `stack test`, which I believe makes use of `Distribution.TestSuite`.

When I get compilation errors, I get file paths and line numbers in the error.  This is great because I can just click on the error in my editor and jump straight to the relevant code.

Other times there is no compilation error and instead I get output like this:

```
### Failure in testFoo: expected: 8
```

This isn't so great, because every time I have to navigate to the relevant test by hand.  Also, it is sometimes ambiguous which assertion has failed, and I have to add a string to label the assertion, which becomes repetitious because the string merely repeats in some form the content of the assertion (or else is meaningless).  With a line number that wouldn't be a problem.

Is there a way to get this setup to print line numbers and file paths for test failures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compilation errors are generated by GHC itself which gives you line numbers, <strike>to my knowledge no test suite has this feature, which would be a really nice thing to have though</strike>. What I found quite helpful is [hspec-expectations-pretty-diff](https://github.com/myfreeweb/hspec-expectations-pretty-diff) which is a nice diffing output <strike>but with no line numbers</strike>, I checked it also provides file path and line number!

[image: example output of hspec-expectations-pretty-diff]

Also I see some space for improvement for your test cases - usually a test case in my project has a string describing the test - therefore it is rarely ambiguous what test case failed. Also you can use the whole power of haskell to generate this `String`!

Comment: Also, the path / line number output is more conventional when using only `Test.Hspec`, rather than `Test.Hspec.Expectations` together than `Test.HUnitPlus`.  The regexp I was already using in emacs parses that output :-)